# C++ operator overloading syntax confusion and memory leak

Tags: c++, class, matrix, memory-management, memory-leaks

I want to make a matrix library for matrixes and their operations but its have a memory issue then i decided to make operator ovarloading for avoid memory leak. = operator overloading dont work for

```
matrix<double> k = func(b);
```

or

```
k = func(b);
```

when i do in for loop

also what is the difference between `matrix& operator=(const matrix& other)` and `matrix<T> operator=(const matrix<T>& other)` ?

Here is a full code for only sum operator. (i have declared bool real for decide is it output of operations such as a + b + c and temporary or permanent)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class matrix{
public:
    T *data;
    int col;
    int row;
    int size;
    bool real;
    
    matrix(int col , int row){// declare matrix<T> r(40,40);
        this->data = new T[col * row];
        this->col = col;
        this->row = row;
        this->size = col * row;
        real = true;
    }
     matrix(){ // declare matrix<T> r;
        this->data = nullptr;
        this->col = -1;
        this->row = -1;
        this->size = -1;
     }
    void print(){
        for(int i=0; i<this->col; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<this->row; j++)
                std::cout << *(this->data + this->row * i + j ) << "  "; //note format is decided to *(data + i) cuz other format is confussing for me whenever 2d matrix. sry
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void operator=(const T& num){// fill
        for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
            *(this->data + i) = (T)num;
    }
    void operator=(matrix<T> other){ // mix
        if(other.real){ // copy
            col = other.col;
            row = other.row;
            size = other.size;
            data = new T[size];
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                *(data + i) = *(other.data + i);
        }
        else{ //replace
            delete data;
            col = other.col;
            row = other.row;
            size = other.size;
            data = other.data;
        }
    }
    // SUM  
    matrix<T> operator+(const matrix<T>& other){
        if(this->real == 1 && other.real == 1){
            matrix<T> r(this->col, this->row);
            for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
                *(r.data + i) = *(this->data + i) + *(other.data + i);
            r.real = false;
            return r;
        }
        else if(this->real == 1 && other.real == 0){
            matrix<T> r = other;
            for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
                *(r.data + i) += *(this->data + i);
            r.real = false;
            return r;
        }
        else if(this->real == 0 && other.real == 1){
            matrix<T> *r = this;
            for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
                *(r->data + i) += *(this->data + i);
            r->real = false;
            return *r;
        }
        else{
            matrix<T> *r = this;
            for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
                *(r->data + i) += *(this->data + i);
            r->real = false;
            delete other.data;
            return *r;
        }
    }
};
template <typename T>
matrix<T> func(matrix<T> a){
    matrix<T> r = a;
    r.real = false; // while its false, gives error. also while its true, gives memory leak  
    r = 3;
    return r;
}



int main(){
    matrix<double> b(20,20);
    b = 2;
    matrix<double> k;
//  for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        k = func(b);
    k.print();
    return 0;
}
```

note:i dont want to use vectors

note:i ll use this matrix lib for neural networks

Comment: whats the issue with the code. Compiler errors? Include them in the question

Comment: why do you not want to use vectors?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: "I don't want to use vector" and you made every possible terrible mistake implementing your own vector. It doesn't match rule of five, it leaks memory and `operator=` is completely worng - you end up with double deletion if you didn't leak the memory.

Comment: you need to read about the rule of 3/5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724

Comment: Rule of three/five/zero, look it up. "(i have declared bool real for decide is it output of operations such as a + b + c and temporary or permanent)" It won't work. C++ has this concept of move semantics, it's been out for 13 years now, use it.

Comment: i used = operator for avoid memory leaks but its gives still shell returned -1073740940 error when line 3 in func is false. When that line is true code gives memory leak error and occupying 2 gb per each second. there are operator+ code cuz its the why i used = operator

Comment: okay i ll look to Rule of three/five/zero

Comment: @Cavemanbob taht won work. On first glace whole code wouldn't work, but your test case is crafted aroud the limitations just to hit the wall that it cannot work.

Comment: Rule of three/five/zero is looking like smart and easy way to do this. i ll use that. my question is answer that should i do close or delete ?

Comment: Replace data with a `std::vector` this will avoid many surprises (and mistakes in memory management). It should be very rare in current C++ programs to even find a new/delete and "owning raw pointers". You might want to have a look at the C++ core guidelines : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: *note:i dont want to use vectors*  But you are willing to use `new`.  `vector` is C++ 101.  `new` is C++ super-advanced tricks that you should know about but never use.

Comment: `matrix<double> k = func(b);` is not an assignment, it's an initialization. It uses the copy constructor, and so does argument passing and returning by value.

Comment: so u are saying that vectors are more than just a little bit better version of stack (i came from C)

Comment: @Cavemanbob vector is implementing pretty much everythign you'd need from a tensor of values, copy\move\assgnment, resizing, iteration, you name it. ALl it lacks is proper operators to do job matrix math does. But even if you wanted self-sufficient matrix (which I have done over dozen of times), it shouldn't have looked like this anyway. It would either mimic a classic object with rule of five OR it will use a flyweight pattern if you have memory pooling in mind. With standard vector there is an option to provide your own allocator method, if you need to pool memory.

Comment: @Cavemanbob `int main() { matrix<double> b(20,20); matrix<double> b2 = b; }` -- Just that two line program has a double-free error.

Comment: @Cavemanbob *note:i dont want to use vectors* -- *note:i ll use this matrix lib for neural networks* -- So here is the deal -- you could waste time trying to get your matrix class to work without vectors, or actually put time into your goal of implementing the neural network portion of your application in a safe and quick(er) manner.  The latter is accomplished by using components that are tested and work (namely `std::vector`).  With the former, you're fighting trying to get your non-vector code to work, and even then, it may not be error-free.

Comment: i have been wrote a actually neural network class for n layers and a neurons for each one and it is working but i have had to go back matrix lib cuz of memory issues. Im a man that want to do everything byself to learn more thing. that is why i have been coded in C and assembly(ftp keylogger) for a while but  u are seems right. Using the libraries is more valuable than knowing how it works.

Comment: @Cavemanbob -- You still have to write the program, even though you may be using `std::vector` -- the application isn't going to magically write itself just because you used vector (or `std::string`, or `std::map`, etc.).   Also `std::vector` is not a "library"  in the sense that it is a third-party or something like that -- `std::vector` has officially been part of C++ for the past 26 years (1998).   If your code uses raw `new[]` and `delete[]`, that program in a modern C++ user-based program is deemed to be at worse, incorrect usage, and at best, dubious usage.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your example of using the matrix

```
k = func(b);

template <typename T>
matrix<T> func(matrix<T> a)  // 0
{
    matrix<T> r = a;  // 1
    r.real = false;
    r = 3;            // 2
    return r;         // 3
}  //4
```

0. You made a copy of real matrix here, from `b` to `a`, by declaring that matrix is taken *by value*. Now you got two matrices, `a` is a local object. Done by `operator=(matrix<T>)` because there is no `matrix::matrix(const matrix&)`, which does create own copy, taking matrix by value. After exiting that operator you got a leak, due not having a destructor;
1. This should have been job for `matrix::matrix(const matrix&)`, but then `operator=(matrix<T>)` is used, another matrix leaks;
2. `operator=(const T& num) is used, all fine. But it's more ideomatical to use constructor and expression like  r = {3};
3. You could make another copy inside of `operator=`, another leak! Compiler may save you from this one, due to NRVO optimization.
4. Memory allocated by `a`  is leaked, and  `r` is leaked if its `real` was true.

Nothing like this would have happen if you created a typical set of five special functions. You can avoid it by not allocating any meory, but having an internal member which does manage it, albeit you would still have problem with excess copies.